React-hook-Form, pass value from a SelectBox to another SelectBox
I find this simple logic problematic.
I'm using react-hook-form, and I assume this should be simple, but I'm still battling it for more than a week.
I'm using nextUI components
 <Checkbox
                className="mt-2 mb-5"
                radius="sm"
                checked={useResAddress}
                onValueChange={handleUseResAddressChange}
              >
                Use Residential Address
              </Checkbox>

This checkBox, when it is true, should pass the values from this Select Box
<Select
                  label="Residenntial Country"
                  placeholder="-Select Country-"
                  isRequired
                  radius="sm"
                  className="font-inter font-medium text-xl"
                  classNames={{
                    trigger: INPUT_STYLES,
                  }}
                  {...register('residenceCountry')}
                >
                  <SelectItem
                    key={'NG'}
                    value={'NG'}
                    classNames={{ title: ['font-inter'] }}
                  >
                    NG
                  </SelectItem>
                </Select>

Pass it to this, since they of the same value, it should work.
<Select
                  label="Correspondence Country"
                  placeholder="-Select Country-"
                  isRequired
                  radius="sm"
                  className="font-inter font-medium text-xl"
                  classNames={{
                    trigger: INPUT_STYLES,
                  }}
                  {...register('correspondenceCountry')}
                >
                  <SelectItem
                    key={'NG'}
                    value={'NG'}
                    classNames={{ title: ['font-inter'] }}
                  >
                    NG
                  </SelectItem>
                </Select>

This is the function that does it
 function handleUseResAddressChange(isChecked: boolean) {
    setUseResAddress(isChecked);
    if (isChecked) {
      const residenceCountry = watch('residenceCountry');
      const residenceState = watch('residenceState');
      const residenceLocalGovernmentCode = watch(
        'residenceLocalGovernmentCode'
      );
      setValue('correspondenceCountry', residenceCountry);
      setValue('correspondenceState', residenceState);
      setValue(
        'correspondenceLocalGovernmentCode',
        residenceLocalGovernmentCode
      );
    } else {

      setValue('correspondenceCountry', '');
      setValue('correspondenceState', '');
      setValue('correspondenceLocalGovernmentCode', '');
    }
  }

The problem is that, it does not work, until I click on an element in my UI.
I am facing an issue where toggling the useResAdress switch does not have any effect. The form has two sections, each enclosed in an accordion. The first input field is in the first accordion while the second input field is in the second accordion. When I toggle the useResAdress switch, nothing happens. However, when I collapse and uncollapse the accordion, the Value appears. I want the value to appear immediately without having to collapse and uncollapse the accordion.
Please help out!
Check it out:
https://file.io/M6P2LfgTadtu

What calls handleUseAddressChange ?  Can you please show the usage of this function?

watch is stateful, it doesn't feel like the correct usage to call it in a function body.

The CheckBox, calls that function

What do you mean by "it does not work until I click on an element"... ?   You toggle on Use Residential Address and nothing happens? Or nothing happens until you make a 2nd interaction with the page after clicking Use Residential Address?  Can you please show more implementation?

I am facing an issue where toggling the useResAdress switch does not have any effect. The form has two sections, each enclosed in an accordion. The first input field is in the first accordion while the second input field is in the second accordion. When I toggle the useResAdress switch, nothing happens. However, when I collapse and uncollapse the accordion, the Value appears. I want the value to appear immediately without having to collapse and uncollapse the accordion.

The first thing that jumps out at me in your code is the watch method being called in a synchronous function body.  watch returns a stateful value.  I'm thinking that this change may help.
 function handleUseResAddressChange(isChecked: boolean) {
    setUseResAddress(isChecked);
    if (isChecked) {
      const [residenceCountry,residenceState,residenceLocalGovernmentCode  = 
         getValues(["residenceCountry", "residenceState", 
         "residenceLocalGovernmentCode"]);
      setValue('correspondenceCountry', residenceCountry);
      setValue('correspondenceState', residenceState);
      setValue(
        'correspondenceLocalGovernmentCode',
        residenceLocalGovernmentCode
      );
    } else {

      setValue('correspondenceCountry', '');
      setValue('correspondenceState', '');
      setValue('correspondenceLocalGovernmentCode', '');
    }
  }

Edit:  I just noticed you are passing isRequired to both of the select components.  I have had issues with that prop causing react-hook-form to stop updating. Please try removing those props from the select components.  If they are required, I think that should be a rule passed to the register function of react-hook-form.  If there are other components that are also passing isRequired please try removing them as well.

Still doesn't update immediately

Hey, can you try removing the isRequired prop you are passing both of the Select components?

Same thing. pLease check the question... i have updated it with the output video

That's a very complicate form.  Since some of the fields update, but the selects do not, it's clearly a problem with the select components themselves.   One trick I have found is to set a key property on a select and then dynamically update that key when I want the select to change value.  What you are seeing by hiding/showing the accordion is forcing that select to re-render.  You can get the same affect by updating the key value.  When the key value changes react forces the component to re-render.

Meaning your selects could watch the value of Use Residential Address and update their keys when that value changes.

The value of useResAddress does not save on the form, because it is not needed, just wanna use it in the UI alone.
Yes, that is what I want

Even if it's not in the form, it could inform some state that those selects can consume.
